# Relations between matrix norms

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition

Let $A \in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})$. Suppose $U_{1} \in M_{(n)\times (n-1)}$ such that columns of $U_{1}$ are orthogonal to each other. Consider the case

$$
B = {U_{1}}^{*} A U_{1}.
$$

Can we say anything about the relationship between matrix norms $||A||$ and $||B||$ (can we say $||B|| \leq ||A||$)?

Plesae let me know if you had any idea.

Comment: What is the definition of a non-square orthogonal matrix?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: It is edited.

Comment: What is $U_1^{*}$ and how do you define norm of a matrix?

Comment: @MostafaAyaz: Hermitian of $U_{1}$ and matrix norm is defined as $$ ||A|| = max_{||x = 1||} ||Ax||_{2}$$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that $||Uv||_p=||v||_p$ for any unitary matrix $U$ ($UU^H=U^HU=I$). Here we have $$\sup_{||x||_p=1}||Bx||_p{=\sup_{||x||_p=1}||U^HAUx||_p\\=\sup_{||Ux||_p=1}||U^HAUx||_p\\=\sup_{||y||_p=1}||U^HAy||_p\\=\sup_{||y||_p=1}||Ay||_p\\=||A||_p}$$therefore $$||B||_p=||A||_p$$

Comment: Thanks @MostafaAyaz. How do you get the 4th equality?

Comment: Well! I used the same argument of equality 2 in equality 4 since they are the same i.e. if $U$ is unitary so is $U^H$. Also you can use SVD (Singular Value Decomposition) to get more precise.